# How to check a string contain alphabet or not

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a simple php program which is getting the data from the url, but I want to check whether it contains a alphabet or not.

The data which I get from the url is as follows `?query=seller,12`. I used `ctype_alpha()` for this, but I am getting no result for this. I have a rough idea that it can be done by `preg_match()` but I don't how to do it.

Please help me as I am beginner to php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to check whether it's all alphabetic or any character is alphabetic?

Comment: Please show your code that use `ctype_alpha`. It should be part of a loop that tests all the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
<?php
   $subject = "?query=seller,12";
   if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $subject)){
      echo "It has a alphabet";
   }
?>
```

if you want to print all the characters from that string, you can use like this

```
preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z]/', $subject,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

$matches is an array of all available matches of the specified pattern

Comment: Thanks for the quick respones. Your program is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude.

```
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $string)) // '/[^a-z\d]/i' should also work.
{
 // string contains only english letters
}
```